# Mariadb galera cluster and cap theorem

Tags: mariadb, galera, cap-theorem

Where does mariadb galera cluster lies according to cap theorem CP or AP based on a brief explanation how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Consistency -- For handling the "critical read" problem, Galera needs a little help.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/galera#critical_reads

Otherwise, one can state that Galera survives "any" single-point-of-failure.

Galera is normally deployed in 3 nodes, one in each of 3 geographic locations.  That means that no single machine failure, data center failure, earthquake, tornado, network outage, etc, can take out more than one node at a time.  The other two nodes (whichever two survive and still talk to each other) will declare that they "have a quorum" and continue to accept writes and deliver reads.  Further, "split brain" is not 'possible'; this is what keeps any attempt at dual-master, even with monitoring from surviving any SPOF.

If the third node or the network is repaired, the Cluster goes about patching up the data as needed, so that the 3 nodes again have identical data.

Granted, this is not quite the same as the definition of CAP, but is is a reasonable goal for a computer cluster.

How it works (in a tiny nutshell)...  Each node talks to each other node.  It does this only during the `COMMIT` of a transaction.  (Hence, it is reasonably efficient even when spread across a WAN, as needed to survive natural disasters.)  The `COMMIT` says to the other nodes "I am about to do this write; is it OK?"  Without actually doing the write, they check Galera's magic sauce to see if it will succeed.  Once everyone says "yes", the `COMMIT` returns success to the client.  (That gives you a hint of the "critical" read issue.)